# RedShift Deep Copy Without INSERT_XID (Hidden metadata) Column Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a very long, narrow table in AWS Redshift. It's that has fallen victim to the issue of the hidden metadata column, INSERT_XID, being hugely disproportionate in size compared to the table.

Picture a table of 632K rows that has 22gb visible data in it and a hidden column with 83gb.

I want to reclaim that space, but [Vacuum has no effect on it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_load_compression_hidden_cols.html)

I tried copying the table:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE test.copied (like prod.table);
INSERT INTO test.copied (select * from prod.table);
COMMIT;
```

This results in a true deep copy where the hidden meta data column is still very large. I was hoping that a copy of the table in one go into a new one would allow the hidden INSERT_XID column to compress, but it failed to do so.

Any ideas how I can optimize this hidden column in AWS Redshift?

I measured the size of each column with the following:

```
SELECT col, attname, COUNT(*) AS "mbs"
FROM stv_blocklist bl
JOIN stv_tbl_perm perm
ON bl.tbl = perm.id AND bl.slice = perm.slice
LEFT JOIN pg_attribute attr ON
attr.attrelid = bl.tbl
AND attr.attnum-1 = bl.col
WHERE perm.name = 'table_name'
GROUP BY col, attname
ORDER BY col;
```

Update:

I also tried an UNLOAD of this table into S3 and then a single COPY back into a new table and he size of the hidden column was unchanged. I'm not sure if this is even resolvable.

Thank you!

Comment: Your math looks a bit off - 100K rows taking up 15GB would mean 150K bytes per row.  This seems high for a narrow table (even if not compressed).  Can you confirm what you are seeing and how you are determining this?

Comment: The example table was hypothetical - I see how it doesn't illustrate my issue well. What I'm actually seeing is a a table with 632K rows with a total size of 107gb. 83gb of that is a metadata column (INSERT_XID) and the visible column is ~22gb. I'll add more detail to the original question on how I determined this

Comment: The math still doesn't add up as near as I can tell.  You have 24gb (non-metadata) for 632K rows.  That's 38kb per row.  Are you working on a very large cluster?  How many slices?  This table is actually small and you are likely running into 1MB quanta effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some math on the numbers you provided and I think you may be running into 1MB block size quanta effects.  However, the math still doesn't work out.

Redshift stores you data around the cluster per the table's distribution style.  For non-diststyle-all tables this means that each column has rows on each slice of the cluster.  The minimum storage size on Redshift, a block, is 1MB in size.  When you have small (for Redshift) number of rows in your table there isn't enough data on each slice to fill up one block so there is a lot of wasted space on disk.

If you have a table of say 2 columns which has 630K rows and you are working on a cluster that has 1024 slices (like 32 nodes of dc2.8xl) then these effects can be quite pronounced.  Each slice has only 615 rows (on average), no where close to filling up a 1MB block.  So the non-metadata portion of this table will take up 2X1024X1MB = 2.048gb.  As you can see, even in this case, I can only get to one tenth of what you are showing.

I could rerun this with 20 columns instead of 2 and I would get up to your 22gb figure but then the size of the metadata columns wouldn't make a whole lot of sense - they aren't that inefficient.  It is possible that I'm not looking at configurations like what you have - 4000 slices?  8 columns?

22gb of space is 22,000 blocks spread across the slices and columns of your cluster / table.  Knowing your column count and cluster configuration will greatly help in understanding how the data is being stored.

Recommendation - move this table to DISTSTYLE ALL and you will save greatly in storage space.  600K rows is tiny for Redshift and spreading the data across all the slices is just inefficient.  Be advised that DISTSTLYE ALL has query compilation implications - mostly positive but not all so monitor your query performance if you make this change.

Comment: We learned a lot about distribution styles as a result of this issue. You were absolutely right about the moving to DISTSTYLE  ALL. The long narrow tables still showed very high block counts for the insert xid column, which we were able to mostly mitigate with changes upstream to how these tables are populated. The vendor design of their product, which is essentially an event stream with timestamps, predated its support for Redshift, so there were issues with things like DISTSTYLE being spread across all slices for no real benefit. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome and thank you for reporting back on cause.